# Can I put a <style>...</style> tag within the body of a HTML file to send in email?

Tags: html, css, email

Since a lot of email clients ignore the HEAD tag, can I embed an inline stylesheet in the body?

Comment: Note: the accepted answer is no longer correct.  See below for recent answers. You CAN use <style> tags (within the <head></head>), and elements can have classes, at least as of 2022.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The short answer is no. Gmail strips the tag and it's content.

Hotmail, Yahoo! Mail and Windows Live Mail does not strip style-tags in the body-element.

But take a look at ["The Ultimate Guide to CSS" for HTML email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) over at Campaign Monitor.

Comment: The guide you've linked to is either out of date or in error on what seems like rather an important point. It indicates that Gmail strips out `<style>` elements regardless of whether they occur in the `<head>` or the `<body>`, but a quick test using http://putsmail.com/ reveals that they are currently not stripped if they occur in the `<head>`. (Gmail does strip classes and ids from all elements, though, which reduces the usefulness of this.)

Comment: Does this is still relevant now, in 2018?

Comment: Yes and no. You cannot use <style /> in the BODY of an email for most clients, but you can use <style /> in the HEAD: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/

Answer (score 8):

Creating an HTML email that works in every email client is hard.  I spent several months refining a good looking template.

http://commadot.com/the-holy-mail/ - original blog with my findings.

http://commadot.com/email-best-practices/ - latest greatest.

Specific answer to your question:  Gmail will be ok with `style=""` but not with a `<style>` block.

Comment: As of 2022, this answer is no longer true of Gmail.  It will accept <style> as long as it is in the <head> section.

Answer (score 5):

Most gmail clients now support embedded CSS as of September 2016, so it should be safe to do.

https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design

Answer (score 2):

The top answer is outdated. Gmail now supports using media query's along with other css properties now - https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. However you have to keep in mind that few email clients respect css standards. Just stick to basic css properties like `margin` and `padding`, etc., and it should all be fine.

Also you can style your html elements inline (`<div style="">`) though it's not an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the accepted answer is out of date.

In my own tests, as of **8/20/2022**, Gmail supports elements with classes, and the use of the `<style>` tag, as long as it is in the `<head>`.  Also, Gmail no longer strips out inline classes for elements.

Example email:

```
<head>
 <style>
   div.mydiv { background-color: blue;  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='mydiv'>This is the contents of my email message!  Thank you 
  google, for observing the style tag!</div>
</body>
```