# Can you place a style block inside a div

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a webapp in VB.NET that uses AJAX to refresh a panel, which in turn holds a control that is a list of items.

The problem I had to solve is that my item list can be filtered by the user selecting values from three different dropdown lists above it.

Under certain filtering conditions, my list items need to be formatted differently, so the CSS that applies to them changes depending on what the user chooses to filter by.

That is the problem statement in a nutshell.

My solution for now was to place a DIV control inside the ASP Panel that AJAX refreshes, and basically do this:

```
<div ID="CSSPlaceHolder" runat="server"></div>
```

Then, from my code behind I do this

```
If GroupMode then
    CSSPlaceHolder.InnerHTML = ""
    CSSPlaceHolder.InnerHTML = MyConditionalCSSFile()
End if
```

This seems to be working, but I am not sure about placing a style block inside a div block.  I don't know if that is normally accepted, and I can't find a rule that tells me a definitive yes or no answer.

When AJAX refreshes the ASP Panel I get the div loaded with my conditionally placed CSS style block.

The solution also looks a lot like a kludge to me.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind this question, I finally found the answer in another post:
[<style> tag inside any elements will still work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385384/style-tag-inside-any-elements-will-still-work)

Searching for "style inside div" is too generic and makes finding the answer very tough :(