# <Style> in body for font-facing

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I've got a "footer.php" page that i'm including in every other page of my website. This footer displays the name of the site at the bottom of the screen. But this footer also uses a custom font, loaded using @font-face.

So until now I had something like this, placed at the end (inside) of the body :

```
div id="scoped-content">
<style type="text/css" scoped>
    @font-face { 
      font-family: 'LilyUPC'; 
      src: url('/common/upcll.ttf'); 
    }

    div.footer {
        position: fixed; 
        bottom: 0; 
        left:0; 
        right:0;
        background-color: black;
        float:down;
        text-align:center;
        z-index: 20;
        font-family: "LilyUPC";
        color:red;
        font-size:12pt;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
</style>
</div>
<a href="/index.php">
    <div class="footer">
        SiteName
    </div>
</a>
```

But recently i've been feeling concerned about writing proper html/CSS, and began validating my whole site using w3c validator.
The only error it shows is the following :

[image]
For the moment, I found nothing helpful on the web.
How can I do the same thing (@font-faceing) without the  tag ?

Note that I cannot put theses declarations in the style.css file, as this footer is used in multiple different sub-sites inside the website where the style.css files differs.

Comment: Then create a `footer.css` file with the footer styles and include it to all your sites

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385384/style-tag-inside-any-elements-will-still-work)

Comment: The problem is that the footer.php file is a single file included in all my webpages, at the bottom of the <body> tag. Including a footer.css file means I must include it in the <head>, resulting in two [include] in every single web page that I write, in two different places. Having to write everything this way would this be terribly fastidious and inefficient.

Comment: If some style is not working in "footer.php", you can use that or missing style in footer.php using <style></style> tag.

Comment: What are you talking about ? I'm already using <style> </style> tag in the footer.php, as I showed in my question.

Comment: 'footer' should be inside of `scoped-content` as a child - to work scoped for it. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp) - anyway there is not enough support for it

Comment: Use <style></style> tag at top of your code, not inside any tag.

Comment: @sTx : Okay understood, done it, but there are still errors.

Comment: @BilluG This is not possible, as the footer.php is included at the end of the body tag. This means that even if I removed the <div id="scoped content"> stuff, it would still be in <body>, and so would trigger an error.

Comment: Best way to use "header.php" with all of your style files, when you will indclude header.php in any other php file, style will work on that php file.

Comment: Doesn't your website have a common css file? Like a css file which have all the common styles for your site? Put the footer style in there

Comment: @Rackover - cannot understand why you can't put `footer` styles in you global styles.css file, `div.footer` mean that only divs with class footer wil have those styles

Comment: @Huangism No : not here, where the site is subdivised in sub-sites that have completely different layouts.

Comment: @sTx The different sub-sites have different layouts, making it impossible to use a global style.css without rewriting the whole site and changing every class name.

Comment: ok, so for the rest of the subsite how did you styled it?

Comment: Which ever sub site this footer belongs to, add the style into that site's common css

Comment: @Huangism The point is displaying the same footer everywhere whatever the current sub-site here : different layouts, but the footer is a constant.

Comment: an alternative would be to write a script into footer.php that would insert some code in head when `footer.php` is required

Comment: @sTx : Well the code that I posted here, up in my question, (<style>declaration inside the body) works perfectly. It's just "not valid" to the w3c validator, which bugs me.

Comment: @sTx This looks neat, how can I do that?

Comment: If this footer is a constant then can't you just add an external css to the main controller template? this would be the main file that includes all other files for sub sites

Comment: @Huangism What do you mean by main controller template ?

Comment: `scoped` only works in mozila 21 as I see

Comment: @Rackover like one file that controls them all. Isn't there a template that includes other sub site files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming because you are putting the `<style>` inside `<div>`. Do not do that. It is better to move that code to internal or separate external CSS.
External CSS is preferred because it increases the reusability.

Comment: I would prefer not make it external for reasons explained in the third comment of the question. How can you make it internal ? If I delete the <div> the error stays the same. Everywhere on the internet it is said to create a "style scoped" element but it still shows as an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, the scoped style concept [has been dropped](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/231) from the HTML spec. Browsers didn't want to implement it. It it supposed to be replaced by Shadow DOM.

Answer (score 1):

`script` in `body` will (likely) be allowed in HTML 5.2 (W3C’s next HTML Recommendation).

The [current HTML 5.2 Working Draft for the `style` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-html52-20170718/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) specifies:

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>
> - Where metadata content is expected.
> - In a `noscript` element that is a child of a `head` element.
> - In the `body`, where flow content is expected.

(This last line is [not included in HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#the-style-element), which is the current HTML Recommendation.)

Here’s the issue asking to update the validator used by the W3C:
[style element conforming in body in w3c HTML](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/489)

Answer (score -1):

Check in inspect element for styles in head

```js
var styles = "<style>"+
    "@font-face { "+
      "font-family: 'LilyUPC'; "+
      "src: url('/common/upcll.ttf');}"+

   "div.footer {"+
        "position: fixed;" +
        "bottom: 0;" +
       "left:0;" +
        "right:0;" +
       "background-color: black;" +
        "float:down;" +
        "text-align:center;" +
        "z-index: 20;"+
        "font-family: 'LilyUPC';" +
        "color:red;" +
        "font-size:12pt;" +
        "text-decoration:underline;}" +
"</style>";

$("head").append(styles);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="other">Unstyled content here</div>
<div class="footer">Styled content here</div>
```

then in php you put this js inside `<script </script>` and echo the whole script

Like this:

```
echo("
     <script>
        var styles = \"<style>\"+
        \"@font-face { \"+
              \"font-family: 'LilyUPC'; \"+
              \"src: url('/common/upcll.ttf');}\"+

         \"div.footer {\"+
               \"position: fixed;\" +
               \"bottom: 0;\" +
               \"left:0;\" +
                \"right:0;\" +
               \"background-color: black;\" +
               \"float:down;\" +
               \"text-align:center;\" +
                \"z-index: 20;\"+
                \"font-family: 'LilyUPC';\" +
                \"color:red;\" +
                \"font-size:12pt;\" +
                \"text-decoration:underline;}\" +
        \"</style>\";

        $(\"head\").append(styles);

     </script>
   ");
```

Comment: I've use jQuery here, to do it with only javascript check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks ! Did it using only javascript. This works !
Just one more question : when I load the page, I've got a slight delay before any JS code executes. Do you know why? (the page is only 14kb)

Comment: because code executes after all html to `footer` has rendered, then after `php require`(or what you do to load footer) has loaded

Comment: you can always make a loading screen on top of all html from body and hide it after code from footer executes, or on `window.onload`(javascript) or `$(document).ready`(jQuery)