# Building HTML emails in 2019, can I put styles in the header section or do I still have to use inline styles?

Tags: html, html-email

This exact question was asked in 2012 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661659/building-html-emails-can-i-put-styles-in-the-header-section-or-do-i-have-to-use).  The consensus was, yes, use in-line styles.

But is this still the case in now 2019?

I have tested in gmail, and it seems to work ok.

So can I stop using inline styles in html emails?

Update: I found [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/) list of email clients that support the header style element.

Comment: Will you have users which use email clients from 2012? Yes, yes you will...

Comment: I find I need to have inline style for Gmail, alternate style for Android, inline styles for Outlook. The biggest issue for me is that my customer base still has a big number of people using Outlook 2002, Outlook 2007 and 2013. None of those have had updates to better support email, so until that happens, we have to inline style and do funky things to get background images.

Comment: I had no idea Outlook 2002 was still in use. I see why the need for inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

It's been more than a year since stopped building HTML emails, but I would say to use in-line styles if you want your emails to display properly in the old versions of Outlook. The only thing I used to put in the head was media queries and some classes to change font-size, colour, etc on smaller breakpoints. Maybe there is a better way to build those now, that´s just my opinion and what worked for me around a year ago :).

Answer (score 1):

Since there are still many ancient email clients being used, no, it's not a good idea.

However, there is one thing I learned that I didn't know when I wrote this and that is that there are tools to inline your styles after the HTML is created.

So you can start with clean html, then run it through an in-liner and then send it out.