# How to created a responsive html email template

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

first of all I know this has been asked a lot like these two : [Building HTML emails ....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661659/building-html-emails-can-i-put-styles-in-the-header-section-or-do-i-have-to-use) and [Can I put a ... tag ....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225828/can-i-put-a-style-style-tag-within-the-body-of-a-html-file-to-send-in-ema) but I didn't find a definite valid
answer !! or I couldn't understand well!!

I already checked [The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/) and it said that using `<style></style>` tag in `<head></head>` is ok by gmail and yahoo as well as `@media` . but my template don't have any style in gmail or yahoo . I want to send responsive emails so I need `@media` also is there any way to use `:nth()` in emails?

I put the snippet below , I really appreciate if someone help me!
I used [putsmail](https://putsmail.com/tests/new) to test it on gmail and yahoo mail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Order</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style type="text/css">
/**
* Avoid browser level font resizing.
* 1. Windows Mobile
* 2. iOS / OSX
*/
body,
table,
td,
a {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
* Remove extra space added to tables and cells in Outlook.
*/
table,
td {
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
}

/**
* Better fluid images in Internet Explorer.
*/
img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

/**
* Remove blue links for iOS devices.
*/
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

/**
* Fix centering issues in Android 4.4.
*/
div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

body {
    max-width: 1100px !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 20px;
}

.rtl{
    direction: rtl;
}
.ltr{
    direction: ltr;
}

/**
* Collapse table borders to avoid space between cells.
*/
/* table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
} */

a {
    color: #1a82e2;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

p{
    margin: 0px;
}
.main-padding{
    padding: 20px;
}
.main_table{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.header_section{
    width: 100%;
    color: #1a1b41;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ffc107;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.title_section{
    width: 100%;
    color: #1a1b41;
    border: 3px solid #1a1b41;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.status_section{
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.status_section--success{
    background-color: #28a745;
}
.status_section--fail{
    background-color: #dc3545;
}
.status_section .icon_wrapper{
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
}
.status_section .icon{
    width: 26px;
    margin: 18px;
}
.items_section_wrapper{
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.items_section{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.items_section .avatar{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.items_section .info{
    padding: 0px 8px;
}
.items_section .info .title{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    text-align: start;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1a1b41;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.items_section .info .location{
    text-align: start;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #505050;
}
.items_section .card{
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.items_section .card .image{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
}
.items_section .card img{
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #a5a5a5;
}
.items_section .card .info_wrapper{
    vertical-align: top;
}
.items_section .card .title{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px;
}
.items_section .card .price{
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
.items_section .card .price{
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
.items_section .card .price-total{
    padding: 8px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-align: end;
}
.items_section .card .sign{
    padding: 0 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.items_section .card .number{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.items_section .card .attr{
    padding: 0px 8px;
}
.items_section .card .dot{
    color: #ff3366;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.rtl .items_section .card .value{
    color: #1a1b41;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: 800;
    float: right;
}
.ltr .items_section .card .value{
    color: #1a1b41;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: 800;
    float: left;
}
.items_section .shipping_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.items_section .shipping_wrapper .icon{
    width: 20px;
}
.details_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
.total_recipient_table-side{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.total_recipient_table-bottom{
    display: none;
}
.detail_table{
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.detail_table .header{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: start;
    padding: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
.detail_table .rows:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #eee;
}
.detail_table .rows .title{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: start;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.detail_table .rows .text{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: end;
}
.btns_section{
    width: 100%;
}
.btns_section .btn_wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.btns_section button{
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    margin: 4px;
}
.btns_section button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btns_section button:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.btn_s{
    background-color: #28a745;
}
.btn_d{
    background-color: #dc3545;
}
.btn_w{
    background-color: #ffc107;
}
.btn_i{
    background-color: #17a2b8;
}
.action_section button{
    background-color: #ffc107;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 150px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
}
.action_section button:hover{
    background-color: #ffc107ee;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.action_section button:focus{
    background-color: #ffc107ee;
    outline: none;
}
.footer_section{
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 3px solid #757575;
}
.footer_section td{
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1a1b41;
}
.footer_section a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1a1b41;
}
.footer_section a:hover{
    color: #ffc107;
}
.mobile{
    display: none;
}
@media (max-device-width: 767px),
 (max-width: 767px) {
    body{
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .main-padding{
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
    .items_section_wrapper{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
    .items_section .card .image{
        width: 25%;
    }
    .items_section .card img{
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .items_section .card .attr{
        padding: 8px 0 0;
    }
    .items_section .card .price{
        padding: 8px 0 0;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .ltr .items_section .card .price{
        float: left;
    }
    .rtl .items_section .card .price{
        float: right;
    }
    .items_section .card .price-total{
        padding: 8px 0 0;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .items_section .card .sign{
        padding: 0 4px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .items_section .card .number{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .total_recipient_table-side{
        display: none;
    }
    .total_recipient_table-bottom{
        display: table-row;
    }
    .desktop{
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile{
        display: table;
    }
}
</style>

</head>
<!-- ltr / rlt -->
<body class="ltr">

    <!-- start preheader -->
    <div class="preheader" style="display: none; max-width: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; color: #fff; opacity: 0;">
        <!-- A preheader is the short summary text that follows the subject line when an email is viewed in the inbox. -->
        Your Order submitted
    </div>
    <!-- end preheader -->

    <!-- start body -->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="main_table">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="main-padding">
                <table class="header_section">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Example.com
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="main-padding">
                <table class="title_section">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Your <span style="color: #ffc107;">Order</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Thanks for choosing us!
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="main-padding">
                <!-- for failed change status_section--success to status_section--fail ALSO img src to times-circle-solid.png -->
                <table class="status_section status_section--success">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:70px;">
                            <div class="icon_wrapper">
                                <img class="icon" src="check-circle-solid.png">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 14px;">
                            payment was successful<span> - your invoice code: </span><span>1235789</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="items_section_wrapper">
                            <table class="items_section">
                                <tr class="vendor">
                                    <td style="width: 40px;">
                                        <img src="1.jpg" class="avatar">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="info">
                                        <p class="title">Vendor Name</p>
                                        <p class="location">location</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="card">
                                        <table style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 0;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="image">
                                                    <img src="1.jpg">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="info_wrapper">
                                                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="title" colspan="2">Lorem Ipsum</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="desktop">
                                                            <td colspan="2" class="attr">
                                                                <p class="value"><span class="dot">&bull; </span>color: red</p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr class="desktop">
                                                            <td class="price">12 $<span class="sign">&times;</span><span class="number">10</span></td>
                                                            <td class="price-total">120 $</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <table style="width: 100%;" class="mobile">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="attr" colspan="1">
                                                                <p class="value"><span class="dot">&bull; </span>color: red</p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <p class="price">12 $<span class="sign">&times;</span><span class="number">10</span></p>
                                                                <p class="price-total">120 $</p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <table class="shipping_wrapper">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 24px;">
                                                    <img src="truck-solid.png" class="icon">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>shipping</td>
                                                <td style="text-align: end;">20 $</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td class="total_recipient_table-side">
                            <table class="details_wrapper">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom:24px;">
                                        <table class="detail_table">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="header" colspan="2">calc</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rows">
                                                <td class="title">Items</td>
                                                <td class="text">120 $</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rows">
                                                <td class="title">Tax Fee</td>
                                                <td class="text">10 $</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rows">
                                                <td class="title">Shipping</td>
                                                <td class="text">20 $</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rows">
                                                <td class="title">Total</td>
                                                <td class="text">150 $</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table class="detail_table">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="header" colspan="2">recipient</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rows">
                                                <td class="title">full name</td>
                                                <td class="text">John Doe</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rows">
                                                <td class="title">email</td>
                                                <td class="text">jdoe@example.com</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rows">
                                                <td class="title">phone</td>
                                                <td class="text">00000000000</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rows">
                                                <td class="title">address</td>
                                                <td class="text">.............</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total_recipient_table-bottom">
            <td class="main-padding">
                <table class="details_wrapper">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-bottom:24px;">
                            <table class="detail_table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="header" colspan="2">calc</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rows">
                                    <td class="title">Items</td>
                                    <td class="text">120 $</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rows">
                                    <td class="title">Tax Fee</td>
                                    <td class="text">10 $</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rows">
                                    <td class="title">Shipping</td>
                                    <td class="text">20 $</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rows">
                                    <td class="title">Total</td>
                                    <td class="text">150 $</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="detail_table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="header" colspan="2">recipient</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rows">
                                    <td class="title">full name</td>
                                    <td class="text">John Doe</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rows">
                                    <td class="title">email</td>
                                    <td class="text">jdoe@example.com</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rows">
                                    <td class="title">phone</td>
                                    <td class="text">00000000000</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rows">
                                    <td class="title">address</td>
                                    <td class="text">.............</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="main-padding">
                <table class="btns_section">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="btn_wrapper">
                            <a href="#"><button class="btn_s">Accept</button></a>
                            <a href="#"><button class="btn_d">Delete</button></a>
                            <a href="#"><button class="btn_w">Reject</button></a>
                            <a href="#"><button class="btn_i">Pend</button></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="main-padding" style="padding-top: 40px;padding-bottom: 40px;">
                <table class="action_section">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#"><button>Button</button></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="main-padding">
                <table class="footer_section">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Copyright &#169; 2020 example.com All rights reserved | <span><a href="#">Home</a></span> | <span><a href="#">Contact Us</a></span> |
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- end body -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encountering two different email bugs here, one in Gmail, and the other in Yahoo. Here’s what’s going on and how to fix it.

## 1. Gmail

Gmail is very picky about certain styles. And whenever Gmail sees something it doesn't like, Gmail will remove the entire `<style>` tag that contains the problematic style. You can [read more about how Gmail removes styles that include special characters here](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/19). In order to find what was wrong with your code, I split your one and only `<style>` tag into multiple ones. Then I sent myself the email and inspected the code in Gmail, and looked at what Gmail kept. I was then able to conclude that what Gmail doesn't like with your code are the `box-shadow` declarations with the `/` syntax.

```css
.detail_table{
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.detail_table .header{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: start;
    padding: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
```

The solution here is simply to isolate the problematic styles in their own `<style>` tag. So remove the two `box-shadow` declarations from your giant `<style>` tag, and add a second `<style>` tag with only the following:

```css
.detail_table{
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
.detail_table .header{
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
```

## 2. Yahoo

I'm assuming you're testing on Yahoo Android. On Android, Yahoo removes content from the `<head>` tag. (You can [read more about this here](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/25).) But it only does so for the first `<head>` tag inside an email. I know what you're thinking, HTML usually has only one `<head>` element anyway. But turns out we can add a second `<head>` tag, and Yahoo will keep the content inside this second `<head>`. So the general practice for this, to get responsive emails to work in Yahoo on Android, is to add an empty `<head>` tag first, and then a real `<head>` with all your content second. Surprisingly, this is very well supported across email clients and rendering engines. Here’s an example:

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Order</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style type="text/css">
    /**
    * Avoid browser level font resizing.
    * 1. Windows Mobile
    * 2. iOS / OSX
    */
    body,
    table,
    td,
    a {
        …
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
…
</body>
</html>
```

Also note that Yahoo has [a bug with CSS comments](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/25) and it’s usually a good practice to remove all CSS comments before sending an email.

Comment: Wow!! just wow! thank you! oh btw , by yahoo I meant yahoo webmail and I can combine your two solutions,  right?

Comment: and how did u test it? I use gmail itself to test. write something in content section, then inspect it and edit as html and paste my html code instead of content. this way I can check both on gmail (sent) and yahoo (inbox) . but doing what you said didn't solve the issue!

Comment: ok , did some test like u said and looks like there are some other issues too. `a[x-apple-data-detectors]` and `div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"]` and `.detail_table .rows:nth-child(even)` cause it to break down ! so by removing theme every thing is fine!! also `box-shadow` wont cause breakdown , just wont show shadows.

Comment: Good job! To answer your question, I tested by sending myself your code using [Putsmail](https://www.putsmail.com) and [Parcel](https://useparcel.com).

Comment: yeah , forgot about putmail !! XD tested with it and both are ok , gonna test with my laravel backend, hope it be fine. for assurance added `!important` to all styles and added them inline too !! XD thanks alot