# What's the simplest way to set the margins for the hr tag?

Tags: html, css

Particularly, I'm looking to set the top and bottom margins.  I tried `margin: 10px 0;`, and it didn't work.  I've googled around, and stuff is either way outdated, or a bad answer.

EDIT: Code

`html`

```
<div id="new_information_section">
    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="info_nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Admissions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The School</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <section id="sat_scores">
                    <div class="chunk">
                        <h3>SAT Scores</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Math: 600-690</li>
                            <li>Reading: 570-690</li>
                            <li>Writing: 560-660</li>
                            <li>Composite: 1130-1320</li>
                            <hr />
                            <li>89% submit</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="chunk">
                        <canvas id="sat_math" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </section> <!-- SAT Scores -->


            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

`css`

```
#new_information_section {
    #info_nav {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .chunk {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        clear: none;
        margin-right: 100px;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: Verdana;
    }
    ul {
        li {
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
        hr {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about it didn't work? Please post an example.

Comment: Is it in email template ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post code because I just thought that setting margins for hr tags didn't work in general, but I'll post code in a sec

Comment: Simple solution: apply new css rules to your list instead of adding <hr> inside of a <ul>. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: @Ani, apply some kind of `<hr>` with `<li>` increases data space (`<ul> | <li> | </li> | </ul>`) instead of simply using `<hr>` tag.

Comment: @FranciscoCarvalho I am not sure what you mean ?...I was telling OP to do it through css instead of using `<hr />`

Comment: @Ani Sorry, misunderstood...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:
**HTML**

```
                    <ul>
                        <li>Math: 600-690</li>
                        <li>Reading: 570-690</li>
                        <li>Writing: 560-660</li>
                        <li>Composite: 1130-1320</li>
                        <li><hr class="myhrline"/></li>
                        <li>89% submit</li>
                    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
  hr.myhrline{
     margin: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Just so I understand, you have to style the class rather than the hr, correct?  Why can you apply some styles to hr, but not others (like margin)?

Comment: Yes, Also include it inside `<li>` tags. The problem was your HTML was not valid. Since you add <hr /> in the middle of the list...instead of adding it inside `<li>` tag. You cannot add anything between `<ul>`  tag except <li>.

Comment: I just tried styling the `<hr />` without adding a class, but having it inside the `<li>` tags, and that worked.  So I guess the problem was the `<li>` tags, and not the class.

Comment: Yes. Problem was with li.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3WkPX/)?

**HTML**

```
<div class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
<hr class="line">
<div class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
hr.line {
    width: 90px;
    color: red;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does indeed work, as evidenced by this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mRHx/).

Note the styling on the hr:

```
hr {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

As Ani has alluded to in the comments, if this is in an email template, you will need to put the style inline, directly on the `hr` element, as follows:

```
<hr style="margin: 10px 0" />
```

Comment: You can include a style tag in HTML encoded emails.  It does not require inline CSS.

Comment: Support for `style` tags is dependent on the email client.  You'll have much better luck putting the styles inline.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225828/can-i-put-a-style-style-tag-within-the-body-of-a-html-file