# How to use font-face in sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts

i am trying to send email in my site with my own font and i have uploaded my font to my site and i used font-face in my mail to use that.
but it does not work and in the send mail there is no font-face.
this is my mail:

```
<style>

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'bmitra';
        src: url(http://roozbehi.ir/Fonts/BMitra.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(http://roozbehi.ir/Fonts/BMitra.woff) format("woff"), url(http://roozbehi.ir/Fonts/BMitra.ttf) format("truetype");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal
    }
    #MailContainer {
        width: 87%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid rgb(204, 214, 220);
        border-top: 5px solid rgb(46, 123, 175);
        padding: 4% 6%;
        color: #666;
        font-family: bmitra;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        font-size: 13.8px;
        line-height: 16px;
        background-color: rgb(249, 251, 251);
        direction: rtl;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
</style>
<div id="MailContainer">

</div>
```

what should i do?

Comment: See also [Can I put a <style>…</style> tag within the body of a HTML file to send in email?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/225828/1207195)

Comment: Does https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/ help? What email client are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use font face tag in email.

You have to use image or text to achieve that.

According to some research by Campaign Monitor, @font-face is only working Apple's Mail.app and the Mail app on iOS.

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/custom-fonts-in-emails/